# How do I store array of NSObject contains in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsobject

I have a class like below

```
import UIKit
....
class MobileContact: NSObject {    
    var mobileNumber : String? = nil
    var type : String? = nil
}
```

I need to store in core data using NSKeyArchiver

Can u plz give one example?

Comment: Core Data and NSKeyArchiver are completely different concepts. Describe more detailed what you actually try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

U can store the object in an array and store it in core data

in .xcdatamodeld file create Entity and add an attribute(of any name) and select type "Transformable".

Or u can just store object under the same attribute rather than storing an array.

Check this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial) for more details of working of core  data in swift